# 'int' object is not callable when using groupby

Tags: python

I am trying to find the longest sequence of numbers in a list using the following code

```
from itertools import groupby
ggg = groupby([1,2,3,3,3,5,88,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3])
max(ggg, key=lambda k: len(list(k[1])))
```

However, I get the error 'int' object is not callable.  Additionally, I am using python 3.

Comment: You probably assigned an `int` to a variable named `max`, `len` or `list` at some point. Your code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> ggg = groupby([1,2,3,3,3,5,88,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3])
>>> max(ggg, key=lambda k: len(list(k[1])))
(9, <itertools._grouper object at 0x019973F0>)
```

As @FamousJameous mentioned, it appears that one of the functions you are using has been assigned to an integer. This is a great illustration of why you should be **careful with what variable names you choose**, since they can wipe away existing functions. Consider:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> len = len(x)
>>> len(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me in Python 3.  My best guess is that your problem is coming from assigning `len`, `list`, or `max` to be an `int`.  For example:

```
>>> list_a = [1, 2]
>>> len(list_a)
2
>>> len = 4
>>> len(list_a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    len(list_a)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.